# Is haram for women to wear men’s clothing?

Tags: clothing, men

Assalamualikum! Recently I’ve been getting really interested in clothing and I stumbled upon men clothing and I really liked the way it looked. When I say that I like men’s clothing I don’t have the intention to imitate a man, I just simply like the way men clothing looks and it’s modest to me because the clothing is loose on my body and I was wondering if wearing men’s clothing is haram because me and my friend were confused since we both like how men’s clothing looks so, I wanted to know is it haram for women to wear men’s clothing but without the intention of imitation of men?

Comment: I'd say the view on what is men's and women's clothing may change over time: For example in the middle east woman used to wear trousers like underwear, while trousers in western societies were men clothes. At the beginning of the last century blue was not a color for boys rather than red in some countries. So the ruling may apply on anything that the society actually regards as such.

Answer (score -1):

Waalaikumsalam,

I have seen a lot like woman wears a man clothing as they are much bigger and lossen. Plus, men clothing are usually unisex and doesn't shows much difference when a woman wears it. If your ni'at to wear men clothing because they are loose and not to imitating a man, then it is absolutely fine.

The points referring to "*the intention of imitation of men*" here is when a person for example a woman, has a strong desire in their hearts to be a man, and vise versa. The person who cross the law of Islam are the one who are cursed by Allah SWT.

Wallahualam.